# Как выгрузить файл с помощью AndroidDevice Monitor?

Tags: java, android-studio

Выгружаю файл из вирт.ус-ва в GenyMotion.

C помощью AndroidDeviceMonitor нахожу нужный файл для выгрузки на компьютер.

Например: "...shared_prefs\settings.xml"

Нажимаю "Push a file onto the device", указываю путь, но AndroidStudio пишет 
 "Failed to push selection: Local path doesn't exist."

Что делаю не так?
Какие еще есть способы?

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю это обычно так:

```
adb pull <file_path_on_device> <path_on_pc>
```

Пример - если хочу выгрузить `shared_prefs\settings.xml`

в терминале набираю:

```
adb pull /data/data/<app_package>/shared_prefs/settings.xml .
```